# Terraform - reference different variable within resource or data source dependent on some logic

Tags: variables, terraform, azure-rm

With this code, I'm planning on having mulitple variables like "vms".  These are key/value maps of VMs and resource groups where I for_each on the data source lookup (backupvm) to get their id.  Then I can add these VMs, using id, as a backup item in vault.

```
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "backupvm" {
for_each             = var.vms
name                 = each.key
resource_group_name  = each.value
}

variable "vms" {
type    = map
default = {
#   "vm name"       = "resource group name"    
    "vaulttestvm1"  = "vaulttestrg"
    "vaulttestvm2"  = "vaulttestrg"
    "vaulttestvm4"  = "vaulttestrg" 
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
name        = var.rg_name
location    = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "vault" {
name                = var.vault_name
location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
sku                 = "Standard"

# change later
soft_delete_enabled = false
}

resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "vms" {
for_each            = var.vms
recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
resource_group_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.resource_group_name
source_vm_id        = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.backupvm[each.key].id
backup_policy_id    = azurerm_backup_policy_vm.VMBackupPolicy.id
}
```

I need a way to reference var.vms, in both the data source & resource, so I could interchange using some logic for another map type variable.  So if it was PowerShell, it would be something like:

```
name = if ($env -eq "prod") { $var.vms } elseif ($env -eq "stage") { $var.vmsstage } elseif ($env -eq "dev") { $var.vmsdev }
```

I've spent a day trying different things but haven't really got close.  I may be somewhat restricted as I need to lookup the vm id using the data source first then loop through my resource (azurerm_backup_protected_vm) dropping that ID in.  A solution to this would prevent me from having to use multiple data sources and resources of the same type.  Thanks!

Comment: 1) Conditional logic like your requirement is an antithesis to Terraform's goal of immutable infrastructure. 2) Your only real method is to use a provisioner such as `local-exec` to perform the conditional logic and then read in the results.

Comment: ok thanks John.  I've instead separated out environments and put vault and related resources into a module then have a different var.vms for each environment.